# Update Notifier pop-up says "Start Dropbox to finish installation."

Tags: updates, dropbox

Upon starting my system, a window pops up and states:

> "*Dropbox Start Required - Start Dropbox to finish installation.*"
>
> [image: window that pops up]

If I <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> then it claims this a window of "Update-notifier". This seems strange. What is going on here?

Things that I have done to try and figure this out:

- `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, but this still comes up,
- checked in "*Settings*" -> "*Online Accounts*", but no Dropbox is linked, and
- ran `rkhunter`, but it only flags well documented false positives.

I don't even have Dropbox (I don't want Dropbox).  I don't have `nautilus-dropbox` installed, but I seemingly have `thunar-dropbox-plugin` installed as I experimented with different DEs at some point. If I press close, it tends to pop up again a little later.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, fully updated.

Comment: It's normal, when you really want to install Dropbox. A Dropbox installation requires some operation like closing and then reopening the file manager and the start of dropbox daemon.
This windows appeared to me every time I have installed dropbox. The real question is: are you sure you didn't install packages like nautilus-dropbox or something similar? What happens if you write in a terminal: apt-cache show nautilus-dropbox? (if you use nautilus as file manager. I'm not currently in front of a pc running Ubuntu, but the command should work). You can try also: dpkg -l | grep "*dropbox*"

Comment: @LorenzKeel Thank you. I don't have nautilus-dropbox installed, but I did seemingly have thunar-dropbox-plugin installed. I experimented with different DEs at some point, so things are little messed up with mounted drives sometimes opening in thunar and sometimes nautilus. Didn't really bother me too much. I uninstalled Dropbox and the thunar plugin. Hopefully that fixes things. I will mark the question as solved if it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appearance of the popup is normal when you are going to install dropbox. A Dropbox installation requires some operations like closing and then reopening the file manager and the start of dropbox daemon. This window appeared to me every time I have installed dropbox.

What you should do is to check if in an indirect way you installed some dropbox packages (such as nautilus-dropbox, thunar-dropbox, nemo-dropbox or caja-dropbox according to the most common file managers).

Writing in a terminal: `apt-cache show nautilus-dropbox` (if you use nautilus as file manager) or `dpkg -l | grep "dropbox"` you should be able if you have dropbox packages in your system, and then decide if you want to keep or remove it.